# Lowercase headers

Tags: header-footer

So I'm writing a book and I managed to put the chapter name on the even pages header and the section name on the odd pages header, and I also could make the chapter name lowercase and my problem now is with the section name, it is all upper case. As shown in the pictures. I want it also to be lowecase. Any solutions!!
[image]

[image]

Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[ paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=22cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```

Comment: Since you're using `fancyhdr`, it's very simple: `\nouppercase{\leftmark}` and `\nouppercase{\rightmark}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as you did for chapters: add

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
```

to your preamble.

[image]

Comment: This worked!! Thanks a lot man